# is there a terminal keycode for enter (to pass to a python script via stdin)

Tags: python, keyboard, stdin, tty

I'm trying to create a commandline remote control in python (running on OSX) that responds to individual key presses.  So far, with the help of [this old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) I've gotten as far as being able to identify and respond to most key presses, but I'd like to give a meaning to the enter key as well.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything like a key code for the enter key.

Failing code:

```
import sys, tty, termios
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

keymaps = {"A": "UP",
           "B": "DOWN",
           "C": "RIGHT",
           "D": "LEFT"}

while True:
    char = getch()
    if char == 'q':
        break
    elif char == '[':
        char2 = getch()
        print(keymaps.get(char2, "keycode not found"))
    elif char == '\n':
        print("ENTER")
    else:
        print(char)
```

when I run this, everything (echoing characters, printing directions) works *except* that pressing enter just prints a blank space rather than, say, the word "ENTER".  I've also tried swapping `\n` out for the empty string, but that still fails.

How do I identify the enter key?

Comment: Try checking for `'\r'`.

Comment: Oh... that was easy.  thank you!  I thought `\r` was only windows...